# ruby - pass receiver as argument in method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out how to pass my "get_hostname" method on the receiver, without using an argument.

For ex:

```
class Hostname
    def initialize(hostname)
        @hostname = hostname

    def get_hostname(hostname)
        b = hostname.split(/[0-9]/)

a = new.Hostname("prod-srv-1")
```

Now, I'd like to be able to call something like:

```
b = a.get_hostname
```

But, I can't figure out a way to do that without passing "a" as an argument, and making get_hostname a class method like:

```
def self.get_hostname(hostname)
    b = Hostname.split(/[0-9]/)
```

Then I can do:

```
b = Hostname.get_hostname(a)
```

But again, I want to pass the receiver without an argument like in my first example. Is this possible?

Comment: Your code looks like Python.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid Ruby. It doesn't make sense to think about the semantics of your code if it cannot even be parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `@hostname` instance variable defined in the initialize method and over that to work in your `get_hostname` method:

```
class Hostname
  def initialize(hostname)
    @hostname = hostname
  end
  def get_hostname
    b = @hostname.split(/[0-9]/)
  end
end

hostname = Hostname.new('prod-srv-1')
p hostname.get_hostname
# => ["prod-srv-"]
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure on what you want to do with `.split(/[0-9]/)`.